# Rails Controller Def Create Redirect to URL upon Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

```
def create
  @purchase = Purchase.new(params[:purchase])

  if session[:purchase_id] != @purchase.save
    redirect_to(@purchase, :notice => "Thank you. You good lookin person you.")
  end
end
```

I'm trying to either

A - Redirect to a URL, or other controllers path, or

B - refresh the form they ordered from (the new_purchases_path) and flash :notice the user that their purchase was successful.  When I try to add a Url (that would be a thank you message page) i get syntax errors. This code redirects the user to the index list (which is inaccesible to them)

If I take  out the `def create`, it by default flashes a notice and shows them their completed form. I'm using simple_form and I'm not sure how to override those defaults. Any suggestions on at least redirecting to a url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examples:

A - Redirect to a URL, or other controllers path

```
  redirect_to :action => "show", :id => 5
  redirect_to "http://www.rubyonrails.org"
  redirect_to  new_purchases_path
  redirect_to  purchases_url
  redirect_to :back
```

B - refresh the form they ordered from (the new_purchases_path)

```
  render :action => "new"
```

Edit:

Here a general example with flash messages:

```
if @foo.save
  redirect_to foos_path, :notice => "Foo saved"
else
  flash[:notice] = "Some errors occured"
  render :action => "new"
end
```

Comment: I tried using
        
       'render :action => "new", :notice => "yay" '

It is refreshing the form, but the notice does't work. If I take the notice out, it routes me to the list again. strange.

Comment: Yea, so just the :notice isn't working. Order works. Just no confimration

Comment: I went with redirect_to URL! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of a create method i made today

```
def create
 @book = Book.new(params[:book])
 if @book.save
  redirect_to searchbook_path, notice: 'Book was successfully saved'
 else
render :action => 'results'
end
```

end

So in your case you could maybe try this

```
def create
@purchase = Purchase.new(params[:purchase])
if @purchase.save
 redirect_to purchase_path, :notice 'Thanks for your purchase'
else
render :action => 'new'
end
end
```

This is assuming that you have a purchase and new path... Though it would help if you could let us know what errors you are getting